# Can I use __consumer_offsets topic to check if message has been consumed?

Tags: apache-kafka

I use Kafka to deliver events between different parts of a system and trying to make sort of feedback to notify producer that event has been consumed.

Are there any pitfalls in consuming messages from system topic `__consumer_offsets`?